# How do I "do-release-upgrade" again?

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade, partial-upgrade

I'm upgrading Ubuntu from 14.04 to 18.04. I ran

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
```

It exited with errors, relating to `emacs` and `emacs24`. I removed those packages with `dpkg`, and I would now like to complete the release upgrade. However, when I try to rerun the `do-release-upgrade`, I get the following error:

```
isaac@isaac-ThinkPad-T440s:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 11, in <module>
    from UpdateManager.Core.MetaRelease import MetaReleaseCore
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py", line 25, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0: symbol _ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE7compareERKS4_, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
```

I get a similar error when I run `apt` or `apt-get`, but `dpkg` seems to be fine. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The partial upgrade appears to have introduced some new code that expects a newer version of libstdc++ to exist. There are two solutions that may work for you:

## Check if a newer libstdc++ exists on your disk

```
$ ls -lh /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.*
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.25
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
```

This shows on my system there is only one `libstdc++` which is `6.0.25` - but for your system there might be multiple with the latest one not correctly linked (the `->` means it's a symbolic link)

You can run this command to force the symbolic link to point to the newer one:

```
sudo ln -s libstdc++.so.6.x.x libstdc++.so.6
```

Replacing `6.x.x` with the most recent version you have.

## Download libstdc++ manually

Download [libstdc++6_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb](https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-8/libstdc++6_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb) and install it using `dpkg`

```
wget 'https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-8/libstdc++6_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb'
dpkg -i libstdc++6_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

If it complains it needs a dependency you will need to repeat the process above for all the packages listed as dependencies (`libc6`, `gcc-8-base`, etc.) They can be found here:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libstdc++6